# Why PhoneGap inAppBrowser event only fired in the second time?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

following code are from phonegap offical website. This is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>InAppBrowser.addEventListener Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
         var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
         ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() { alert('start: ' + event.url); });
         ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() { alert('stop: ' + event.url); });
         ref.addEventListener('exit', function() { alert(event.type); });
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

After this, I made a button. when click the button then open the in app browser.

```
function onDeviceReady() {
   $('#btn').click(function(){
       var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
       ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() { alert('start: ' + event.url); });
       ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() { alert('stop: ' + event.url); });
       ref.addEventListener('exit', function() { alert(event.type); });
   });
}
```

when I click the button in the first time, no alerts. So I click done button to close the browser. Then I click the button second time, the alerts are working. I re-deploy the program and repeat this. the results are same, the alerts are only fired at the second time when I click the button. Could someone tell me why?

Comment: what version of PhoneGap are you using? I think I've got the same issue where the events only fire the second time - very odd - although it is *only* on iOS7 where the problem exists (but problem does not exist on iOS 5, 6, or Android 2.2 and 4.4). I'm using PhoneGap 3.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
it maybe because you are declaring var ref inside click function

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>InAppBrowser.removeEventListener Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Global InAppBrowser reference
    var ref= null;

    function iabLoadStart(event) {
        alert(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);
    }

    function iabLoadStop(event) {
        alert(event.type + ' - ' + event.url);
    }

    function iabLoadError(event) {
        alert(event.type + ' - ' + event.message);
    }

    function iabClose(event) {
         alert(event.type);
         ref.removeEventListener('loadstart', iabLoadStart);
         ref.removeEventListener('loadstop', iabLoadStop);
         ref.removeEventListener('loaderror', iabLoadError);
         ref.removeEventListener('exit', iabClose);
    }

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
      $('#btn').click(function(){
         ref= window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
         ref.addEventListener('loadstart', iabLoadStart);
         ref.addEventListener('loadstop', iabLoadStop);
         ref.removeEventListener('loaderror', iabLoadError);
         ref.addEventListener('exit', iabClose);
       });
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <button id='btn'>click me</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried on two different devices. Both of them are only fired the event at the second click.

Comment: Did u try with fresh project

Comment: @Vicky what version of PhoneGap did you try this on? And did you try it with an iOS7 device?

Comment: Also, @nich, when you tried the code from @vicky, did you copy and paste the code, or just update the `var ref` declaration? Because I read elsewhere that the issue you describe is possibly fixed by updating the function declarations to use the latest PhoneGap version of the function 'signatures' - by adding the word `event` to the function definition. ie. `function iabLoadStart(event)`